# Using react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome with styled-components

Tags: react-native, font-awesome, styled-components

I'm refactoring some React Native code to use [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com), but having trouble styling FontAwesome icons. I get an error such as

> styledComponents2.default.IconFontAwesome is not a function

so I understand per [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1410) that I need to wrap the component and pass the `className` prop down [per the docs on extending custom components](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-components). So I have this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import IconFontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledTouchableOpacity = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  width: ${props => (props.large ? '100%' : '80%')};
  height: ${props => (props.large ? '80px' : '60px')};
  font-size: ${props => (props.large ? '18px' : '15px')};
  background: '#f1d746';
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
`;

const StyledText = styled.Text`
  font-size: 15;
  font-weight: bold;
`;

const StylableIcon = ({ className }) => (
  <IconFontAwesome className={className} />
);

const StyledIconFontAwesome = styled.StylableIcon`
  font-size: 15;
  padding: 10px;
`;

const Button = (props) => {
  let _icon = null;

  if (props.icon) {
    _icon = (
      <StyledIconFontAwesome name={props.icon} />
    );
  }

  return (
    <StyledTouchableOpacity>
      <StyledText>{props.text}</StyledText>
      {_icon}
    </StyledTouchableOpacity>
  );
};

Button.defaultProps = {
  icon: null,
};

Button.propTypes = {
  icon: PropTypes.string,
};

export default Button;
```

which results in a similar error

> styledComponents2.default.StylableIcon is not a function

Any tips on what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks all.

Comment: There is a note in [the document link u shared](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-components) that If you are using react-native keep in mind to use style instead of className. Still you are using className. Can u recheck that?

Comment: I'm not sure but `styled.StylableIcon` might be needed to be `styled(StylableIcon)`

Answer (score 1):

OK got it working with:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import IconFontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledTouchableOpacity = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  width: ${props => (props.large ? '100%' : '80%')};
  height: ${props => (props.large ? '80px' : '60px')};
  font-size: ${props => (props.large ? '18px' : '15px')};
  background: '#f1d746';
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
`;

const StyledText = styled.Text`
  font-size: 15;
  font-weight: bold;
`;

const StyledIconFontAwesome = styled(IconFontAwesome)`
  font-size: 15;
  padding: 10px;
`;

const Button = (props) => {
  let _icon = null;

  if (props.icon) {
    _icon = (
      <StyledIconFontAwesome name={props.icon} />
    );
  }

  return (
    <StyledTouchableOpacity>
      <StyledText>{props.text}</StyledText>
      {_icon}
    </StyledTouchableOpacity>
  );
};

Button.defaultProps = {
  icon: null,
};

Button.propTypes = {
  icon: PropTypes.string,
};

export default Button;
```

So two fixes here:

1. Had to use the syntax `styled(Something)` as opposed to `styled.Something`  (thanks @bennygenel)
2. The wrapper `StylableIcon` was unnecessary. I can call `styled(IconFontAwesome)` directly.